# We have $\gcd(2^{2019}, 3^{2019})=1$. Solve $2^{2019}k \equiv 1 \mod{3^{2019}}$ and $3^{2019}j \equiv 1 \mod{2^{2019}}$ for $k$ and $j$ integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

We have $\gcd(2^{2019}, 3^{2019})=1$. Solve $2^{2019}k \equiv 1  \mod{3^{2019}}$ and $3^{2019}j \equiv 1  \mod{2^{2019}}$ for $k$ and $j$ integers. I have tried to find the solution of the diophantine $1=2^{2019}k -3^{2019}j$ equation but I have not succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

By Euler's theorem,

$$
2^{\phi(3^{2019})}\equiv 1 \ \mathrm{mod} \ 3^{2019},
$$

and we have $\phi(3^{2019})=(3-1)3^{2018} = 2 \cdot 3^{2018}>2019$.

Thus, we can take 
$$
k=2^{2\cdot 3^{2018} - 2019}.
$$

It is possible to find $j$ by the similar process.

Answer (score 1):

$ 2 \times2^{-1} ≡ 1 ≡ 1 + 3^{2019} \mod 3^{2019}$

$$k ≡ (2^{-1})^{2019} ≡ \left({1 + 3^{2019} \over 2}\right)^{2019} \mod 3^{2019}$$

$ 3 \times3^{-1} ≡ 1 ≡ 1 + 2^{2019} \mod 2^{2019}$

$$j ≡ (3^{-1})^{2019} ≡ \left({1 + 2^{2019} \over 3}\right)^{2019} \mod 2^{2019}$$

Result confirmed in Python

```
>>> b2 = 2**2019
>>> b3 = 3**2019
>>> k = pow((1+b3)//2, 2019, b3)
>>> j = pow((1+b2)//3, 2019, b2)
>>>
>>> k*b2 % b3, j*b3 % b2
(1L, 1L)
```

---

We can reduce computation further, by doing only j, with the smaller pow-of-2 mod.

$$k ≡ {1 - (3^{2019} )j \over 2^{2019}} ≡ -\Bigl\lfloor {(3^{2019} )j \over 2^{2019}} \Bigr\rfloor \mod 3^{2019}$$

Comment: My solution is using Euler's theorem. The result is almost impossible to calculate, but it shows an expression for such number. In my opinion, yours is much faster and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat dirty answer comes from a trick occasionally used in similar situations. My goal is to give you more than what was required, namely integers $u$ and $v$ such that
$$3^{2019}u+2^{2019}v=1.$$
The catch is that while I give a recipe for a pair of such integers $(u,v)$, the resulting formula is not really suited for efficient calculations.

We have the obvious identity
$$3-2=1.$$
Raise both sides of this to the power $2\cdot2019-1=4037$ to arrive at
$$
(3-2)^{4037}=1.
$$
Expand the left hand side using the binomial formula. The exponents $j,k$ in a term involving $3^j2^k$ satisfy $j+k=4037$, so you see that all the terms are divisible by either $3^{2019}$ or $2^{2019}$. Collect the terms together according to which holds.

---

One more general setting, where the same trick works is the case of a ring $R$ together with two ideals $I,J$ such that $I+J=R$. The trick then gives a proof for the fact that for all positive integers $n,m$ we still have $I^n+J^m$ even though the powers of ideals are more often than not strictly smaller the higher the exponent. Anyway, the assumption gives the existence of $i\in I, j\in J$ such that $i+j=1$. Then also $(i+j)^{n+m+1}=1_R$, and we can proceed as above. The identity $i+j=1$ implies that $i$ and $j$ commute, and hence the binomial formula works even without assuming that $R$ would be commutative.

Comment: Nicely done! One typo on $(3-2)^{4028}$, should be $^{4038}$.

Comment: Thanks, @SungjinKim. I also forgot that we can actually decrease the exponent by one.

Comment: That's a special case of the common Bezout-based proof of $\,(a,b)=1\,\Rightarrow\, (a^n,b^n) = 1.\,$ While it works fine to prove the  *existence* of the Bezout identity for the $n$'th powers, it is not an efficient way to compute it, so I don't think this is a feasible method to "**solve** for $k$ and $j$". It's worth emphasizing that in the answer since that may be clear to some readers.

Comment: @BillDubuque I agree. That's more or less exactly what I had in mind, when writing *a somewhat dirty answer*. Don't have the time to edit now. Will clarify later.